# JS: Как найти позицию курсора относительно многострочного inline-элемента

Tags: javascript, dom

Итак.

Есть список inline-элементов, идущих подряд друг за другом. Каждый из них может быть как в одну, так и в две и более строк.
Нужно при наведении курсора понять, на каком проценте от начала до конца inline-элемента, на который мы навели, мы находимся.

По буквам разбивать контент span'ов нет возможности (внутри может быть не только текст, но и изображения разной ширины).

Наглядный пример задачи в коде:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(_span => {
  _span.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    // Some handler
    console.log(e);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
}

span:before {
  content: '';
}

span:nth-child(1) {
  background: #f00;
}

span:nth-child(2) {
  background: #ff0;
}

span:nth-child(3) {
  background: #f0f;
}

span:nth-child(4) {
  background: #0ff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Loren inpum Loren inpum Loren inpum</span>
  <span>Loren inpum Loren inpum Loren inpum</span>
  <span>Loren inpum Loren inpum Loren inpum</span>
  <span>Loren inpum Loren inpum Loren inpum</span>
</div>
```

У меня нет проблемы получить позицию курсора. Есть проблема с получением корректной позиции span-элемента, а именно проблема с пониманием DOM'ом, что многострочный inline-элемент (в моём случае, span) начинается не с левого края родителя, а в его центре, а заканчивается не в самом правом крае родителя на следующей строке, а в его середине. Плюс требуется калькулирование позиции курсора в процентах относительно левого верхнего края span'а. `_span.getBoundingClientRect()` выдаёт информацию, как будто span - это блочный элемент, и что он занимает всю строку слева направо (а не с центра).

Comment: А зачем это нужно? Я уверен, что есть способ сделать то, что вы хотите намного быстрее и правильнее.

Comment: @РоманТатаринов У меня есть специализированный конструктор многострочных формул с ограничением по горизонтали и вертикальным скроллом.

При перетаскивании нового элемента из бокового меню (посредством Drag&Drop) в формулу - нужно определять, наводим ли мы его на первую половину элемента, уже находящегося в формуле, либо на вторую половину, чтобы в соответствии с этим добавлять курсор перед ним или после.

Comment: а какой вывод нужен?

Comment: @Air, сначала попробуй то, что советуешь

Comment: @Air, ключевые слова в данной задаче: "многострочный inline-элемент". Дописал в конце вопроса, почему эта задача не может быть решена в пару строк.

Comment: @Grundy Требуется высчитать позицию курсора относительно элемента: на каком проценте с левого края визуальной части span-элемента (который находится почти в конце первой строки) до правого края визуальной части span-элемента (который находится в начале второй строки) находится курсор. Логика практически та же, что и высчитывание положения курсора в textarea, когда мы получаем номер символа, на котором находится курсор, и общее количество символов, и можем рассчитать, на каком проценте от начала текста находится курсор.